# AppHarbor gives 403 after push to GitHub

Tags: github, umbraco, appharbor

I'm testing AppHarbor with a .NET CMS called Umbraco.

I'm uploading the CMS through the CLI, and running the installation without any problems and everything works flawlessly.  Then I set GitHub to deploy to my application on push, and then everything goes haywire.

After the push has been deployed, my application returns a 403.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Another person's issue and also mine has been resolved by following the steps:

1. Remove the line:

```html
<Import Project="..\packages\AutoMapper.3.2.1\tools\AutoMapper.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\AutoMapper.3.2.1\tools\AutoMapper.targets')" />
```

from the Web application .csproj file.

2. Build your solution in Visual Studio
3. Push changes to GitHub

If you push to development branch you might need to manually click on the "Deploy" button in the Build Status section on the AppHarbor Management website.

I have found the solution ["403 - Forbidden: Access is denied"](https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/65117-403-forbidden-access-is-denied) on the AppHarbor Support page. Hope that helps!